# How to Write UPDATE SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql

The following query throws an exception and I don't know why:

> Message: Test method MainTest.MySkillDevelopmentTests.SupervisorFieldAndNamePresent threw exception: 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ' where UserName = '.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

Code:

```
public static List<List<string>> SetMyGpidAsSupervisorGPID(string gpid)
{
     string query = string.Format("UPDATE [" + dbName + "].[dbo].[MasterDatas] "
                                + "SET SupervisorGPID = " + gpid + "'"
                                + " WHERE UserName = strenev");
    return ConnectToDB(query);
}
```

Comment: Why use string.Format when you're still using the basic level of concatenation?

Comment: What is not clear about the error message? Enclose the text of the username with '. And use proper sql parameters!

Comment: SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: i cant even look at string.format anymore I always use `$""` now

Comment: Even the name of this is worrisome... Are you allowing the user to make their user a supervisor? Hopefully that doesn't include elevated permissions...

Comment: Gpid = "'; Drop table masterdatas;"

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Interpolation ;)

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne that's it, can never remember the name, I just say dollar formatting :D:D

Comment: @AleksandarTodorov - You may like to accept the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to accept an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string.Format() in this case, when what you already have is a string.

Your query is missing an enclosing single-quote over 2 places. Use the following code:

```
string query = "UPDATE [" + dbName + "].[dbo].[MasterDatas] "
                                + "SET SupervisorGPID = '" // here ' is missing
                                + gpid + "'"
                                + " WHERE UserName = 'strenev'"; // here surrounding '' is missing
```

By the way, you need to study more about SQL-Injection, etc. to know that this is not a good/safe practice.

---

**EDIT based on the comments** (thanks for the suggestion):

Code without SQL-Injection (reference: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)):

```
string query = "UPDATE [dbname].[dbo].[MasterDatas] "
  //// assuming dbName is not a variable which a user-decides as it generally can't be, and rather a fixed string.
                + "SET SupervisorGPID = @gpid"+
               + " WHERE UserName = 'strenev'"; // here surrounding '' is missing
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@dbName", SqlDbType.NVarchar);
    command.Parameters["@dbName"].Value = dbName;
    command.Parameters.Add("@gpID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@gpID"].Value = gpid;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //catch and handle OR throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can do better than this. Why don't you add the code to avoid the SQL Injection? Giving this kind of answer will not help the OP.

Comment: do not `throw ex;`. Write `throw;` instead as this will preserve the stack trace. In the case above, since you are not doing anything with the exception, just omit the try/catch completely.

Comment: There is still a problem. The dbname cannot be parameterized. We can only hope that this value is not typed by the user but choosen from a whitelist of allowed database names (perhaps it is not required at all) However this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: A better choice would be to set the [Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.database(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `SqlConnection` instead of setting it in the query itself. That would avoid the possibility of a sql injection attack.

Comment: @Igor - About the throwing of exception, it was supposed to be a comment. Regarding the database name setting, it should be part of connectinString, which has been not shared as the same is missing in the question. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

String constants must be surrounded by single quotes.

```
where UserName='strenev';      // surround with quotes.
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it's correct

Comment: Glad your answer is better :-)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful there's another constant that isn't surrounded by single quotes

Comment: @buffjape - It's not about whose answer is better, but rather make OP/others things clear so that they have a good learning curve. I've also grown on SO, and so I'm rendering what I've learnt.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful - clearer is better. Just take the compliment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized queries instead for example in your case
UserName = @name and use sqlcommand inside which you could reference the sql parameter @name and the value 'strenev' in it. Refer to 
[Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

```
"UPDATE [" + dbName + "].[dbo].[MasterDatas] "
                                    + "SET SupervisorGPID = " + gpid 
                                    + " WHERE UserName = 'strenev'");
```

Comment: This is still wrong at all levels.

Comment: @Steve he said he had error at UserName. If UserName is varchar2 it will go through.

Comment: No this is totally wrong. You have a single quote after gpid and before the WHERE statement. But even if you fix it, it is still wrong because you leave the SQL Injection problem unresolved

Comment: @steve keep fighting the good fight!

Comment: @Steve you are right I edited it. But sometimes you may need a quick fix for intranet application to show it to the client. But I am totally with you regarding sql injections

Comment: and then your POC intranet library gets used in a publicly facing production application, and then your company is in the news for a data breach.